# How to prevent access to WordPress blog by ip?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am having problems as some computer from an IP address is trying to access all the files on my server.

How should I change the `.htaccess` file so that IP address gets NO access at all to any files? And which `.htaccess` file do I change? It looks like I have one inside each folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic mod_access module should get you what you need

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Something like that. I dont know the exact syntax. Keep in mind that depending on your exact version of Apache (1.3/2.0/2.2) then the module requirements might be different. I think in 2.2 you need the authz_host module, but in 1.3 its mod_access.

Comment: which htaccess file do i add this to?

Comment: You would probably want to put it in the root of your app (whether thats the overall document root of your site, I dont know). But yeah, the application root.

Answer (score 1):

For simple cases, you can try http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-ban/, which can keep IP or IP range from visiting your blog.

If that's not enough, you can modify .htaccess as follows

> Deny from xx.xx.xx.xx/xx
>
> Allow from ALL

Answer (score 1):

Another way, this time using `mod_rewrite` rules in a `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^123.123.123.123$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blocked.html [L,F]
```

`[L,F]` means 'stop executing further rules, and return `403 Forbidden` as the HTTP status'. `blocked.html` could contain a message indicating that they've been blocked.

Comment: does this block all files and folders inside the server? do i have to wrap it with <files></files> or something?

Comment: Yes, this will block all files and folders (^(.*)$ means match every URL). No need for a wrapper.